# Installation Error ("Unexpected error when typed "heroku" ")

Tags: node.js, heroku, command-line-interface

I am trying to install heroku CLI using this command "wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh"

Eveything seems to be going at first. But after completition when i type "**heroku --version**", following error pops up.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/heroku-cli/bin/run:12
const {run} = require('@cli-engine/engine')
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

I don't have any idea how to proceed. I have searched the internet to my capabilities and still unable to find a solution.

I have tried installing using "**npm install -g heroku-cli**" but still getting the same error.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: which node version are you using?

Comment: node version 4.2.6 and npm v3.5.2

Comment: update node to version 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heroku-cli` requires a minimum node version of `6.15.24`. Upgrade your node. The latest stable version of node is `8.9.4`